# How to Pass Variables in ASP.NET PostBack?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I'm trying to pass variables back to an ASP.NET web page by PostBack. The status variables for button presses are stored in ViewState. The problem here is that I need to press the button twice before the changed status is sent to the page.

The ViewState is read by Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ViewState["Print"] = "Small";
        Response.Write ("Status: " + ViewState["Status"].ToString());
    }
    else
        Response.Write ("Status: " + ViewState["Status"].ToString());
}
```

The ViewState for a button press is set by:

```
protected void ImageButton_LargeStatus_Click (object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["Status"] = "Large";
}
```

Why do I need to press the ImageButton twice to change the ViewState?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the "!"?

Comment: What are you expecting? `ImageButton_LargeStatus_Click` is run after a PostBack and after `Page_Load` in that PostBack. So you can only view "Large" in a second PostBack.

Answer (score 0):

Because 1st time you are updating ViewState with wrong key...

Replace below line

ViewState["Print"] = "Small";

with

ViewState["Status"] = "Small";

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo while editing the code. All of the ViewState's are ViewState ["Status"], but they requires 2 imagebutton presses to update to correct value.